# RevenueCat storeProblem when trying to purchase product

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I am fetching products from revenuecat there is no problem with that I can see product details from console and they are correct from Google Play Console but the problem is that (in only Android) when I try to purchase something I am getting following error:

```
E/[Purchases] - ERROR( 8481): ‼️ Failed to launch billing intent. DebugMessage: Service connection is disconnected.. ErrorCode: SERVICE_DISCONNECTED.
E/[Purchases] - ERROR( 8481): ‼️ BillingWrapper purchases failed to update: DebugMessage: Service connection is disconnected.. ErrorCode: SERVICE_DISCONNECTED.null
E/[Purchases] - ERROR( 8481): ‼️ There was a problem with the Play Store.
```

Steps I produce:

- I configured products on google play console
- I connected revenuecat to google play account (it is connected)
- enabled pub/sub api
- created service accounts and connected them to google play and give permissions for the current app
- entered products to revenuecat

As I said there is no problem with IOS only in Android (I can make purchase in IOS). But I can fetch them without problem I can see details. But I cannot purchase.

Comment: Is there an existing version of the app on the play store? Or has this app not been released yet? Google makes it difficult to test IAPs if the app hasn't been released yet

Comment: The app is not released, it is on closed track. But that is not the problem, if problem could be that, than billing windows should open then it should give 'this version of the app is not configured for billing' error. But it is not opening the billing windows at all

Comment: @BurakCabadan Are you testing on a real device?

Comment: Yes I am testing on a real device

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77206225/service-unavailable-error-when-fetching-products-an-internal-error-occurred-re Can anyone help me with a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved problem after 2 weeks of research by removing `tools:node="replace"` line from the android manifest file